# TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined in react js

Tags: reactjs

this is my html code in react Component:

```
<a className="nav-link" href="#" onClick={this.handleExit}>
     <img
         src={require("../data/btn-ex.png")}
         style={{ width: "70px" }}
         alt="btn"
     />
</a>
```

and this my function to use logout:

```
handleExit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (window.confirm("برای خروج اطمینان دارید؟")) {
      this.props.history.replace("/logout");
    }
};
```

but this is not working

```js
const require = () => 'https://api.adorable.io/avatars/285/abott@adorable.png'

class App extends React.Component {
  handleExit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (window.confirm("برای خروج اطمینان دارید؟")) {
      this.props.history.replace("/logout");
    }
  };

  render () {
    return (
      <a className="nav-link" href="#" onClick={this.handleExit}>
        <img src={require("../data/btn-ex.png")} style={{
            width: "70px"
          }} alt="btn"/>
      </a>
    )  
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: `this.props.history` is `undefined`

Comment: How do you pass `history` prop?

Comment: what can I do @DennisVash ?

Comment: no I dont know @RomanOks ?

Comment: @mahmood_kd can you share code in sandbox?

Comment: check props has history if not then wrap component with `withRouter` from 'react-router-dom'. if you have history then use this.props.history.push('/logout');

Comment: @mahmood_kd To use props you must call component with some argument. `<NameOfComponent history={something} />`. Now `this.props.history` eq `something`. If you don't pass a prop, you cannot use methods on this prop.

Comment: I fixed it but not the way you still grateful @ArshpreetWadehra . I use Link in react-router-dom

Comment: I fixed it but not the way you still grateful  @RomanOks . I use Link in react-router-dom

Comment: using Link will skip the confirm dialog @mahmood_kd

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use  withRouter with your React component

```
 import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
   import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

        class YourReactComponent extends PureComponent {

         handleExit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (window.confirm("برای خروج اطمینان دارید؟")) {
          this.props.history.replace("/logout");
        }
    };

          render() {


            return(
    <a className="nav-link" href="#" onClick={this.handleExit}>
         <img
             src={require("../data/btn-ex.png")}
             style={{ width: "70px" }}
             alt="btn"
         />
    </a>

            )

          }

        }

        export default withRouter(YourReactComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is work very good

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

    class Navbar extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
    ....
   <Link className="nav-link" to="/dashboard/logout">
         <img
               src={require("../data/btn-ex.png")}
               style={{ width: "70px" }}
               alt="btn"
         />
   </Link>

    ...
        );
      }
    }
    export default Navbar;
```